# Understanding python & numpy syntax to mask and filter array

Tags: python, numpy

Please help me understand how the lines below are working.

1. How does a pair of parentheses create an array and then individual
   elements go through logical condition check and create a new array?
2. How does condition in square brackets filter elements create another sub-array?

   ```
   import numpy as np
   my_vector=np.array([-17, 4, 0, 2, 21, 37, 105]) 

                       array([-17,   4,   0,   2,  21,  37, 105]) 

   zero_mod_7_mask= 0 == (my_vector % 7) #question 1 

                       array([False, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True])

   my_subarray = my_vector[zero_mod_7_mask] # question 2

                       array([  0,  21, 105])
   ```

Comment: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.06-boolean-arrays-and-masks.html

Comment: `my_vector%7` is one calculation.  The () just ensues that's done first.  May no be needed.  Then `0==...` test - true if that array value is 0.

Comment: 2. Well, it's just keeping the elements that are `True`.

Comment: I recommend reading the [indexing reference](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html). I'll add that in terms of your first question, the parentheses are not actually specific to numpy array creation or anything of the sorts.

Answer (score 0):

1. The parentheses do nothing but ensure that what's inside of them is done first
2. The array just keeps the `True` elements

Answer (score 0):

In a `ipython` interactive session:

```
In [230]: my_vector=np.array([-17, 4, 0, 2, 21, 37, 105])
```

The modulus calculation:

```
In [231]: my_vector%7                                                           
Out[231]: array([4, 4, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0])
```

identifying elements of that which are 0:

```
In [232]: 0 == my_vector%7                                                      
Out[232]: array([False, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True])
```

Indexes of those `True` elements:

```
In [233]: np.nonzero(_)                                                         
Out[233]: (array([2, 4, 6]),)
```

Selecting those elements from `my_vector`:

```
In [234]: my_vector[_]                                                          
Out[234]: array([  0,  21, 105])
```

Doing the same with the boolean array:

```
In [235]: my_vector[Out[232]]                                                   
Out[235]: array([  0,  21, 105])
```