# Understanding bracket filter syntax in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How does the following filter out the results in `pandas` ? For example, with this statement:

```
df[['name', 'id', 'group']][df.id.notnull()]
```

I get 426 rows (it filters out everything where `df.group IS NOT NULL`). However, if I just use that syntax by itself, it returns a `bool` for each row, `{index: bool`}:

```
[df.group.notnull()]
```

How does the bracket notation work with `pandas` ? Another example would be:

```
df.id[df.id==458514]            # filters out rows
# vs 
[df.id==458514]                 # returns a bool
```

Comment: A better syntax for the first line is `df.loc[df['id'].notna(), ['name', 'id', 'group']]`.   Use loc to get all rows where 'ID' is not null and only select columns 'Name', 'ID' and 'Group'.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59241738/understanding-python-numpy-syntax-to-mask-and-filter-array

Comment: the benefit of ScottBoston's option is you can then use that filter to assign values as in `df.loc[...] = any_value`, your example would fail in this case

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer, just a breakdown of `df.id[df.id==458514]`

- `df.id` returns a series with the contents of column `id`
- `df.id[...]` slices that series with either 1) a boolean mask, 2) a single index label or a list of them, 3) a slice of labels in the form `start:end:step`. If it receives a boolean mask then it must be of the same shape as the series being sliced. If it receives index label(s) then it will return those specific rows. Sliciing works just as with python lists, but `start` and `end` be integer locations or index labels (e.g. `['a':'e']` will return all rows in between, including `'e'`).
- `df.id[df.id==458514]` returns a filtered series with your boolean mask, i.e. only the items where `df.id` equals `458514`. It also works with other boolean masks as in `df.id[df.name == 'Carl']` or  `df.id[df.name.isin(['Tom', 'Jerry'])]`.

Read more in [panda's intro to data structures](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/dsintro.html#intro-to-data-structures)