# Meaning of r[( s== 'even'::2) in python function

Tags: python, indexing

Question that asks:

> "Create a function that returns the characters from a list or string r
> on odd or even positions, depending on the specifier s. The specifier
> will be "odd" for items on odd positions (1, 3, 5, ...) and "even" for
> items on even positions (2, 4, 6, ...)."
>
> E.g. char_at_pos([2, 4, 6, 8, 10], "even") ➞ [4, 8]

Have managed to solve, but saw a quicker way to solve would be to use:

```py
def char_at_pos(r, s):
    return r[s == 'even'::2]
```

am wondering how to interpret `r[s == 'even'::2]`, is that adding a condition inside the index bracket before we pick the even index numbers in the list? How does it then also pick the odd numbers?

Comment: I answered a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63713092/6692898) earlier today... is it a dupe?

Answer (score 4):

`r[s == 'even'::2]`

`s == 'even'` evaluates to 1 (which is the numerical equivalent for True) if `s` is 'even', otherwise it evaluates to zero (which is the numerical equivalent for False). Now lets break it down based on examples:

- `r[1:10]` takes all items startig at 1 till item 10 (excluded).
- `r[1:]` takes all items starting at 1 till the end.
- `r[1:10:2]` takes every second item starting at 1 till item 10, and
- `r[1::2]` correspondingly takes every second item starting at 1 till the end.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the @jim answer,

Booleans in Python are implemented as a subclass of integers.

```
>>> int(True)
1
>>> int(False)
0
>>> issubclass(type(True), int)
True
>>> issubclass(type(False), int)
True
```

When you call `r[s == 'even'::2]` python calls the [`__getitem__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L2811) method of the list object with the slice object `slice(True, None, None)` or `slice(False, None, None)`[Depends upon the result of `s == 'even'`]. The [PySlice_Unpack](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L2829) C API call will extract the start, stop, step data members from a slice object as C integers. So this is where the `start`(`boolean` object) argument is actually is converting to an `int` object making the expression to be evaluated as same as `r[1::2]` or `r[0::2]`

Comment: Interesting, is this the same in other languages? I had the idea that boolean in VisualBasic was just one bit of memory 1/0... any idea why this was not done in Python to save memory?

Comment: Nevermind, here is an alternative https://stackoverflow.com/q/142812/6692898

Comment: Interesting. It seems like you can indeed add True and False in python, True + True gives 2!