# Boolean Condition in a linkedin course

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a new beginner in python and am taking the school's online course on LinkedIn. In the last chapter, the lecturer wrote down as:

```
allyears.groupby(['sex','name'])['number'].sum()

totals = allyears.groupby(['sex','name'])['number'].sum()

def sumsq(x):
    return sum(x**2)

spikyness = allyears.groupby(['sex','name'])['number'].agg(sumsq)/totals**2

totals_recent = allyears[allyears['year'] > 2005].groupby(['sex','name'])['number'].sum()

spiky_common = spikyness[(totals > 5000) & (totals_recent < 1000)].copy()
spiky_common = spiky_common.sort_values(ascending = False)
```

My question is, since the `spikyness` did not include `totals_recent` in, why it can be as a boolean condition in `spiky_common` ?

===================

Update:

1. allyears table looks like this:
   [allyears.head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyDRS.png)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your confusion -- if `spikyness` is a Pandas DataFrame and it did not include `totals_recent` in it, then I wouldn't think that this expression is valid: `spikyness[(totals > 5000) & (totals_recent < 1000)]`.

However, its hard to tell because it seems like the code snippet in the question doesn't have all of the code involved. For instance, its not clear where the data in `allyears` is coming from. Is there more code that goes with this example?

---

edit
This code snippet helps define allyears in the question:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'name': ['Mary', 'Anna', 'Emma', 'Elizabeth', 'Minnie'], 
     'sex': ['F','F','F','F','F'],
     'number': [7065, 2604, 2003, 1939, 1746],
     'year' : [1880, 1880, 1880, 1880, 1880]}
allyears = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Comment: Thanks, GandhiGandhi! Basically that's all of the code I think... I checked again, other command lines are teaching how to draw a picture etc. What actually confuses me is the condition 'totals_recent' worked out if with 'totals > 5000', while becoming an error when set it as a single condition. I added the form of the 'allyears' in the question, if that helps?

Comment: I think that helps me see the problem -- I edited my answer with a snippet to let you generate `allyears`. I think I understand why it works now. Try printing out `totals > 5000` now -- that returns a boolean mask of each row. It doesn't matter if spikyness contains a `totals_recent` column, but because you can use the `totals_recent` series to create a boolean mask that applies to `allyears`. This link helped me understand what's happening https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63713092/understanding-bracket-filter-syntax-in-pandas